# initial $stateParams empty?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[Plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/FAiCihUcVML9Ssb6SVJX?p=preview)

I am using UI-Router for a simple single page application. It is a just a table that you can sort and filter. When you apply a filter, like ordering a column in ascending order, the URL updates to something like:

`www.domain.com#/column/'column name'/desc/false/`

I then grab the paramters using $stateParams, and update the table accordingly.

```
 $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $scope.sorting.predicate = toParams.column;
            $scope.sorting.reverse = boolVal(toParams.sort);
        });
```

However, if I were to visit `www.domain.com#/column/'column name'/desc/false/`,
the table doesn't *load* with the data filtered. I am trying the following (after injecting $stateParams to my controller):

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, viewConfig) {
            console.log('VCL stateParams: ' + angular.toJson($stateParams));
        });
```

However, stateParams is always empty regardless of the URL (only on viewContentLoaded). I can't seem to get the parameters of the URL on page load. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Here is the state config:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("name", {
            url: '/column/:column/desc/:sort/',
            controller: 'Ctrl',
            resolve: {
                logSomeParams: ['$stateParams', '$state', function ($stateParams, $state) {
                    console.log($stateParams);
                    console.log(this); // this is the state you transitioned From.
                    console.log($state); // this is the state you transitioned To.
                }]
            }
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }
]);
```

Here is how the state change is called:

```
<a ui-sref="name({column:'\''+column+'\'',sort:sorting.reverse})" 
ng-click="sorting.predicate = '\'' + column + '\''; sorting.reverse=!sorting.reverse;">
{{column}}</a>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce with a plunkr? Edit: I ask because I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Yes, I will get right on that. I think something else in my code is breaking.

Comment: What's going on with all those single quotes and slashes in your `ui-sref`? Seems like you have some mis-matched quotes, and the slashes really aren't necessary. Can't you just do: `ui-sref="name(column: column, sort: sort:sorting.reverse})"`  Also, the `ng-click` changes values of the parameters that are fed to the `ui-sref` -- how do you know which one happens first?

Comment: Excellent observations! The quotes are because the SQL guy has columns with spaces, so without quotes it causes problems. as far as the `ng-click/ui-sref`, valid point. I'm actually not sure. I would assume `ng-click` because after the initial load everything works.

Comment: Ah makes perfect sense, don't know why I didn't read them as backslash escaped characters :) And since it works as expected, I would guess that the `ng-click` directive has a higher priority than `ui-sref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, quite unfortunate how simple the answer was. I needed to inject `$state`. I only injected `$stateParams`. You need both. Hope this saves someone some hair pulling and screaming.

Comment: Thank you so much. Searched so long for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options I'd investigate further.

**Option 1**: $rootScope listener

```
 $scope.$root.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   $scope.sorting.predicate = toParams.column;
   $scope.sorting.reverse = boolVal(toParams.sort);
 });

 $scope.$root.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, viewConfig) {
   console.log('VCL stateParams: ' + angular.toJson($stateParams));
 });
```

**Option 2**: Resolve objects

In your state definition, try to add this:

```
resolve: {
  logSomeParams: ['$stateParams', '$state', function ($stateParams, $state) {
    console.log($stateParams);
    console.log(this); // this is the state you transitioned From.
    console.log($state); // this is the state you transitioned To.
  }]
}
```

Please give either of those a go and let me know what results you get. 
The resolve object should run prior to $viewContentLoaded, but since all you are really interested in are the stateParams in your $viewContentLoaded callback, might aswell put it in the state definition.

Good luck,
Kasper.

**Edit**:

Try giving your state a parent state with the resolve object.

Like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('parentState', {
  url: '',
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
    logSomeParams: ['$stateParams', '$state', function ($stateParams, $state) {
      console.log($stateParams);
      console.log(this); // this is the state you transitioned From.
      console.log($state); // this is the state you transitioned To.
    }]
  }      
});

$stateProvider.state("name", {
  url: '/column/:column/desc/:sort/',
  parent: 'parentState',
  controller: 'Ctrl'
});
```

Let me know how that works out for ya.

Comment: Hmmm, the resolve doesn't get called until _after_ I click on a column, activating a state change. Is that what is supposed to happen? I feel like something else in my code is breaking.

Comment: Do I need to set the state somewhere, or does it do it automatically? I think what is happening is the state isn't set until after I click the ui-sref.

Comment: Aye, that would probably be it since your initial state when loading up the application isnt necessarily the state definition holding your resolve object. 

I'll edit my answer in just a few.

Comment: `$stateParams` is still miraculously empty. :(

Comment: I think a plunker is what we need at this point, guesswork can only get one so far. Starting to run dry here on ideas y'know :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am working on one right now!